# activeClassName does not work on the sideMenu when clicking on the link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a sidebar menu which imports a child component  containing a list of menu items. I want to set the activeClassName to each of the `<Link />` in the child component `<SideMenuContainer />`. However, the active link only works on the page load.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SideMenuContainer from './SideMenu/SideMenuContainer';

export default class CompanyInfoMenu extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.toggleShow = this.toggleShow.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isShow: false,
    };
  }

  toggleShow() {
    this.setState({ isShow: !this.state.isShow });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>   
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span onClick={() => this.toggleShow()}>button</span>
            {this.state.isShow ? <ul><SideMenuContainer /></ul> : <div></div>}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The routing looks like this

```
<IndexRedirect to="client-info" />
<Route path="client-info" component={ClientInfoSection}>
  <IndexRedirect to="BasicInformation" />
  <Route path=":itemType" component={ItemContentContainer} />
  <Route path="company-introduction" component={CompanyInformationContainer} />
</Route>
```

When the `:itemType` changes, the activeClassName doesn't apply.

The `<SideMenuContainer />` looks like this

```
return (
  <ul>
      <li>
        <Link
          to={`/client-info/${item.itemType}`}
          activeClassName="active"
        >
          item1
        </Link>
      </li>
  </ul>
);
```

Comment: I don't see any `<Link/>` or `activeClassName` in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known bug for dynamic routes in react-router v2.x.x: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3286

To get the routes work properly you should add `{ pure: false }` to the connect() parameters:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,
                       mapDispatchToProps,
                       null,
                       { pure: false })(SideMenuContainer);
```