# React router Link; activeClassName not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a navigation component which renders each navigation link. 
The return of this component looks like this:

```
     return (
        <li key={`nav-list-${el.title}-${index}`}>
          <Link to={{pathname: '/c/' + el.urlkey}}
                activeClassName={s.active}>{el.title}</Link>
          {subNav}
        </li>
      );
```

The active class is only set on a page refresh. When clicking through the links the active indicator stays at the initial link.

I'm not using Redux so it doesn't seem to be related to this issue: [activeClassName does not work on the sideMenu when clicking on the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40125929/activeclassname-does-not-work-on-the-sidemenu-when-clicking-on-the-link)

My route look like this:

```
      <Route path="/c/:category(/:title)" component={CategoryView} name="category" />
```

using React-Router 2.8.1 and browserHistory

Comment: had the same issue, problem was related to the fact that the component which had the activeClassName was not the component i passed to <Route /> so it was not getting updated by React. Wrapping my component inside withRouter did the trick!

Comment: Did you try using <NavLink /> instead of <Link />?

Comment: @ArustamyanG. For me, your solution is correct. I read the documment, https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter I , I cann't understand why it works. can you explain more about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to upgrade just yet as it was causing more issues than it resolved. And I wasn't using Redux so the whole connect thing didn't apply. I tried render both pure and unpure (using the pure-render decorator) with no result.

So I decided to write the link handling manually. It's super verbose I know but it works!

I added the router context:

```
static contextTypes = {
   router: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

The render returns:

```
return (
   <li key={`nav-${el.title}`} className={`${isActiveClass}`}>
     <a onClick={this.state.LinkClick} data-item={urlkey}>{el.title}</a>
   </li>
);
```

The click handler looks like this:

```
LinkClick(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   const elem = e.currentTarget;
   const item = elem.dataset.item;
   this.context.router.push('/c/'+item);
   this.setState({
     activeLink: item
   });
 }
```

Finally I set the class in the render:

```
  const activeLink = this.state.activeLink;
  let isActiveClass = '';
  let navLinks = map(availableCategories, (el, index) => {
  const urlkey = el.urlkey;

  // Check the active item on page render
  const isActive = this.context.router.isActive('/c/' + urlkey);

  if(activeLink === urlkey || isActive){
    isActiveClass = s.active;
  } else {
    isActiveClass = '';
  }
```

Answer (score 26):

### Instructions

1. Use `<NavLink>` instead of `<Link>` and add exact as a property
2. Include `exact` as a property to ensure `activeClassName` only triggers on url paths that match your location exactly

### Example

```
<NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to="/path1">
<NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to="/path2">
```

### Source

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/exact-bool

> exact: bool
>
> When true, the active class/style will only be applied if the location is matched exactly.

Comment: keep in mind, IF for whatever retarded reason you are passing an object to the "to" part of the NavLink like this:
to={{pathname:menu.goto, label:menu.label}}
then you might have to do a bit more checking.

Comment: @adnantariq - Why is it retarded to pass an object?

Answer (score 8):

In the case that you are here because activeClassName does not work at all. Be informed that it has been deprecated starting from react-router 6. Instead use className as a function that takes a prop and return class names. as in

```
<NavLink className={({isActive}) => isActive ? "active-class": "non-active-class" } > </Navlink>
```

isActive is a boolean indicating whether the route is the current.

Reference: [react router docs](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink)

Comment: This is the solution guys. My code works now. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome @ChidiebereEzeokwelume

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to debug without seeing the complete code but problems with React Router `activeClassName` can often be solved by either:

- Making sure that you have one `IndexLink`:

  `<li><IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Home</IndexLink></li>
   <li><Link to="/" activeClassName="active">About</Link></li>
   <li><Link to="/" activeClassName="active">Contact</Link></li>`
- Or using the `onlyActiveOnIndex` attribute on all `Links`:

  `<li><Link to="/" activeClassName="active" onlyActiveOnIndex>Home</Link></li>
   <li><Link to="/" activeClassName="active" onlyActiveOnIndex>About</Link></li>
   <li><Link to="/" activeClassName="active" onlyActiveOnIndex>Contact</Link></li>`

Here is a working demo of a second solution: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/qaKqRW

Comment: I worry it has to do with the fact that I'm looping the component. I tried adding the 'onlyActiveOnIndex ' but sadly to no avail. I also already have  a IndexLink but that is outside of the looping component. Thanks for the help though, anything else you might think of would be great!

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue! Resolved by wrapping the parent component via `withRouter`. E.g.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class NavBar extends Component {
    ...
}

export default withRouter(NavBar);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
<NavLink
  to="/faq"
  activeClassName="selected"
>FAQs</NavLink>
```

from [ReactTraining](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md) 
did it for me

Comment: activeClassName="selected" did NOT work for me. 
What it worked was: activeClassName="active". I am using react-router-dom v4.3

Answer (score 1):

Please check the `react-router-dom` version in your project.

One difference as of v6.0.0-beta.3 is that `activeClassName` and `activeStyle` have been removed from NavLinkProps.
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link

Instead, you can pass a function to either style or className that will allow you to customize the inline styling or the class string based on the component's active state.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions for this:

- You could upgrade to the latest stable version `v3.0.0` (released
  today) where this issue is fixed. (see https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3286#issuecomment-220861601)
- <strike>Apply the fix for `v2.8.1` from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40126703</strike>

Edit: you're not using Redux so the second solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem in react-router-dom v4.3. and my entire App was already wrapped using withRouter. I'm also using react-redux. I noticed that it would add class to the correct link.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
    router: state.router,
    location: state.route.location
 }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header)
```

and my navigation links looked like this

```
 <NavLink
        exact
        to="/logs"
        className="menu-item"
        activeClassName="selected"
        >
        <i className="st-icon-log-reports" /> logs 
 </NavLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be dumb, but this wasn't working for me because I was importing the similarly named NavLink from `reactstrap` instead of `react-router-dom`.

I was doing this:

```
import { NavLink } from 'reactstrap';
```

But `reactstrap`'s version of NavLink doesn't offer the activeClassName attribute.

So I switched to this:

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Note you may have to manually add `className="nav-link"` to your `NavLink` elements to get your styles to look the same.